# Dependencies of puppet modules

Tags: puppet, provisioning

I am trying to get acquainted with puppet, so here is my n00b question.

In a module I want to use there are some includes, like

```
include gcc
include wget
```

If I just install this module and use it in my manifest, I will get an error that classes from these modules are not found. At least this happens when using puppet provisioning for vagrant boxes on their "up". So I have to install these modules too.

I haven't came across with documentation saying that a particular module is dependent on others. So in order to figure out what I am missing, I have to run it a figure it out from errors.

Am I doing something wrong or why is it such a lame approach?

Answer (score 1):

Puppet looks up for modules in *$modulepath*. Run `puppet config print modulepath` to find out the path.

In your case this files must exist:

- *$modulepath/gcc/manifests/init.pp* OR *$modulepath/gcc/manifests/gcc.pp*
- *$modulepath/wget/manifests/init.pp* OR *$modulepath/wget/manifests/wget.pp*

Comment: Ok, but it's strange that if I have many third-party modules, I can't figure out if they depend on anything by looking at docs. Only running and failing them